# How to generate html for text in JTextArea?

Tags: java, html, jtextarea

I have a problem in generating html code for a given string which is from

```
JTextArea textArea=new JTextArea(10,10);
String textToHtml=textArea.getText();
```

In this generated html code, it should contain with all **html** tags which are related to the given string.

Like `<p>something like this</p>`, `<br>` and etc. 
Also this is not a web application. If you have any idea how do this. Suggest me. Thanks.

**Update**

For an example, if I type a text with line breaks, it should automatically insert `<br>` or `<p>`. This kind of function is available in Dreamweaver. It automatically inserts the code when you start filling the content in the webpage. The issue is so I don't want the non-technical usres to type the HTML code when they are writing paragraphs, because by default the

tag and all are inserted. I will be emailing this directly to the user after this text is typed, so this formatting is essential.

It is important to note that I don't know what the user will type, it is all upto him. so whatever the method I use should be capable of identfying the places where it could put tags (like paragraph tag) and move on

Comment: I don´t get what you want. could you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: `JTextArea` won't render styled text (markup)

Comment: Use `JTextPane` instead of `JTextArea`.

Comment: Actually I want to get the string from JTextArea and generate a html code including the string in it.

Comment: @Satya - Ok I will try it .

Comment: @KevinEsche: Please check the update

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Please check the update

Comment: Use a `DocumentFilter`

Comment: if you wanna html editor component check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893429/java-wysiwyg-html-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For an example, if I type a text with line breaks, it should automatically insert `<br>` or `<p>`

The basic requirement would be to use a `DocumentFilter` to inject your markup when ever they type enter

[image: Markup]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class TestMarkup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestMarkup();
    }

    public TestMarkup() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));

            ((AbstractDocument) ta.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {

                @Override
                public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                    if (text.endsWith("\n")) {
                        super.replace(fb, offset, 0, "<br>", attrs);
                        offset += 4;
                    }
                    super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Inserting `<p>`/`</p>` "might" be more difficult, but, if you assume that your first line starts with `<p>`, it's just a matter of inject `</p>` before the newline and `<p>` after it, then append the remaining text...

**Updated with Paragraph support and pasting**

Apparently I just can't walk away...

[image: Markup]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.Element;

public class TestMarkup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestMarkup();
    }

    public TestMarkup() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));

            ((AbstractDocument) ta.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {

                protected String getLastLineOfText(Document document) throws BadLocationException {
                    // Find the last line of text...
                    Element rootElem = document.getDefaultRootElement();
                    int numLines = rootElem.getElementCount();
                    Element lineElem = rootElem.getElement(numLines - 1);
                    int lineStart = lineElem.getStartOffset();
                    int lineEnd = lineElem.getEndOffset();
                    String lineText = document.getText(lineStart, lineEnd - lineStart);
                    return lineText;
                }

                @Override
                public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                    if (text.length() > 1) {

                        String lastLineOfText = getLastLineOfText(fb.getDocument());
                        if (!lastLineOfText.startsWith("<p>")) {
                            if (!text.startsWith("<p>")) {
                                text = "<p>" + text;
                            }
                        }

                        // Replace any line breaks with a new line
                        String[] lines = text.split("\n");
                        if (lines.length > 0) {

                            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("<br>\n");
                            for (String line : lines) {
                                sj.add(line);
                            }
                            text = sj.toString();

                        }

                        if (!text.endsWith("</p>")) {
                            text += "</p>";
                        }

                        super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);

                    } else {

                        String postInsert = null;
                        if (text.endsWith("\n")) {

                            // Find the last line of text...
                            String lastLineOfText = getLastLineOfText(fb.getDocument());
                            lastLineOfText = lastLineOfText.substring(0, lastLineOfText.length() - 1);
                            postInsert = "<p>";
                            if (!lastLineOfText.endsWith("</p>")) {

                                super.replace(fb, offset, 0, "</p>", attrs);
                                offset += 4;
                            }
                        }
                        super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
                        if (postInsert != null) {
                            offset += text.length();
                            super.replace(fb, offset, 0, "<p>", attrs);
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MadProgrammer , Thank you very much and I will try on this .

Comment: Thank you very much MadProgrammer . You give the most suitable answer for me . Once again thank you very much for your contribution .

Comment: I fixed a minor issue in the second example, but I didn't update the gif ;)

Comment: Ok . I will get it as you wish . Anyway thanks a lot . And wish you all the best .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
String textToHtml="something like this";
textToHtml = "<p>".concat(textToHtml).concat("</p>").concat("<br>");
```

Comment: Well this is not I really expected . For an example  when read some lines in JTextArea , generated html code should include `<br>` , `<p></p>` tags . And also I use this JTextArea for input the string which should contain in html . It may be couple of lines or paragraphs or etc .

Comment: @Barrier You can create some templates with full html page representation and adding your text from `JTextArea` to this templates.