# Limit number of character on every JTextArea line

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, documentfilter

I have a `JTextArea` in a `JDialog`. `JDialog` uses a `GridLayout`.

I would like to have 7 digits on each line of the `JTextArea` (each line will be a 7 `int` registration number). For user experience reasons, I would like the `JTextArea` to either add a new line or stop expanding when it reaches 7 characters on a line.

Things that didn't work : 
- Specifying the number of columns in the `JTextArea` constructor
- `matriculesText.setLineWrap(true);` and `matriculesText.setWrapStyleWord(true);`

I'm afraid `uploadDialogManager.setHgap(20);` might be breaking the code. I'm wondering if the `JDialog` should rather have a fixed size.

This is how I construct my `JDialog` :

```
// initialization
    Dialog uploadParent = null;
    JDialog uploadDialog = new JDialog(uploadParent);
    GridLayout uploadDialogManager = new GridLayout(UPLOAD_DIALOG_ROWS, 
UPLOAD_DIALOG_COLUMNS);

    // uploadDialog properties
    uploadDialog.setSize(new Dimension(UPLOAD_DIALOG_WIDTH, UPLOAD_DIALOG_HEIGHT));
    uploadDialog.setLayout(uploadDialogManager);
    uploadDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    //Set up the horizontal gap value
    uploadDialogManager.setHgap(20);
    //Set up the vertical gap value
    uploadDialogManager.setVgap(20);
    //Set up the layout of the buttons
    //uploadDialogManager.layoutContainer();

    // components initialization
    JLabel exerciceLabel = new JLabel("exercice number : ");
    JComboBox<Integer> exerciceNumbers = new JComboBox<Integer> 
  (EXERCICE_NUMBERS);
    JLabel matriculeLabel = new JLabel("please enter your matricules, one per 
  line : ");
    JTextArea matriculesText = new JTextArea(1, 1);
    JButton confirm = new JButton("confirm");
    JButton cancel = new JButton("cancel");

    matriculesText.setLineWrap(true);
    matriculesText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Comment: Use a JTextField to enter the data. You can easily limit the text to 7 by using a `DocumentFilter`. Then the user can use the Enter key or click a button to move the data to the text area. Or maybe you should move the data to a JList so the data can processed separately.

Comment: 7 x `new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1000000,1000000,9999999,1));`..

Comment: It's a rather complicated requirement, but you need to start with a `DocumentFilter`, the trick is knowing when you have a new line. Maybe something like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433508/how-to-generate-html-for-text-in-jtextarea/32434040#32434040) might give you a starting point.  Personally, I think you're going to continually have issues with this approach. I agree with what has already been suggested, limit to the input to a single field which will give you better control and then display the results in a different component

Comment: thanks all for your feedback ! I rechecked my requirements with my supervisor. I should be fine with `String.split("\n")`, then use a regex to check every divided string. (I'll try this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made another solution that fills my requirements. Instead of going to a new line when 7 characters are reached, I use `MATRICULE_REGEX` to check if every line contains 7 digits (`1\\d{6}`). If it doesn't, I reject the `JTextArea` content.

```
    private static final String MATRICULE_REGEX = "1\\d{6}(\\n1\\d{6})*";

    Pattern matriculePattern = Pattern.compile(MATRICULE_REGEX);
    Matcher matriculeMatcher = null;
    matriculeMatcher = matriculePattern.matcher(text);
    isValidMatricule = matriculeMatcher.matches();
```